# Print the arguments that were passed to gdb from within gdb?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I have a gdb shell provided by an IDE(VSCode). The debugging experience isn't great there so I'd like to use gdb from the command line. But because of the complications of build system and the way commands are invoked, I don't know what arguments were passed to gdb.

Is it possible to print the arguments that were passed to gdb from within gdb?

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: This is on Linux

Comment: Can you give an example of what you pass to gdb and what do you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to print the arguments that were passed to gdb from within gdb?

I don't believe so.

You could attach the running GDB with *another* GDB, and look at its `argv[]` (provided you have install debug info for GDB), but a much simpler solution is to look at `/proc/${gdb_pid}/cmdline`.

> This is on Linux

The following command should get you all you want:

```
cat -v /proc/$(pgrep gdb)/cmdline
```

**Update:**

> i get `/usr/bin/gdb^@--interpreter=mi^@--tty=/dev/pts/5^@`

This answers your question: GDB was invoked as:

```
/usr/bin/gdb --interpreter=mi --tty=/dev/pts/5
```

It then follows that all the other actions: loading executable, attaching to a process or starting one from the beginning, etc. were done by giving GDB commands (`file /path/to/a.out`, `start`, etc.)

These commands should be discoverable in the GDB console (VSCode provides access to it *somewhere*) and you should look for them there.

Comment: with `cat -v /proc/$(pgrep gdb)/cmdline`  i get `/usr/bin/gdb^@--interpreter=mi^@--tty=/dev/pts/5^@`

Comment: @A.K. Were you expecting something substantially different?

Comment: As per the answer, i was expecting something like: `<binary> [args...]`. binary being the program i'm debugging.

Comment: @A.K. I've updated the answer. Your expectations are incorrect.

Comment: Makes sense now. btw i was able to find the arguments passed to the program by looking at `ps aux | grep <program>`, as the program was still running under the debugger.